# Document Picker ios 8 extension, not importing file from directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am using document picker extension for my app. I have used both the extensions i.e document file provider and document provider for creating local app directory. My files are being saved successfully in the shared file provider group. When I try to access files from third party apps like google drive, dropbox or iCloud, it works like a charm. But When I try to access documents from my app's directory, an empty file is copied to the temp directory of the app. I donot get the contents of the file. My code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func attachDocuments(sender: AnyObject) {

    let documentUTIs: NSArray = [ kUTTypePlainText as NSString , kUTTypePDF , kUTTypePNG , kUTTypeJPEG , kUTTypeText , kUTTypeContent ]
    let menuVC = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: documentUTIs as! [String], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)

    menuVC.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(menuVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "fromCommentsView")
}

func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {

    let myData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        if myData != nil {
        self.uploadDocWebservice(url!, progressView: progressView, index: String(selectedDocNamesArray.count-1), imageData: myData, name: docName, mimeType: docExtension , uploadType: "Doc" )
        }else {

            let button = UIButton()
            button.tag = attachedDocArray.count + 1
            self.deleteDocAction(button)
            invokeAlertMethod("Error", msgBody: "File not supported", delegate: self)
        }

}

func documentMenuWasCancelled(documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController) {

}

func documentMenu(documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(documentPicker, animated: true) { () -> Void in

    }
}
```